# Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'clientRepository';

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jakarta-ee

Hello  every  am  new to  spring  and am  trying to  create  a simple  application  for CRUD but i have  been  getting the  error  below.
Am using  STS

Before  i past  my solution  i will like to  list  the  solution  i tried without success .

[[java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46246104/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-not-a-managed-type][1)

[UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41511511/unsatisfieddependencyexception-error-creating-bean-with-name/49251441)

[Spring + JPA - Why I receive the error java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.PersistenceContext.properties()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11817712/spring-jpa-why-i-receive-the-error-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-javax-persis#)

[Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48435364/post-processing-of-merged-bean-definition-failed-nested-exception-is-java-lang)

but i still get  the same error

Error creating bean with name 'clientServiceImpli': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'clientRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'clientReposito':

Here goes  my  code

// My  ClientRepo

```
@Repository
public interface ClientReposito extends JpaRepository<ClientDao, Long>  {



}
```

//My Entity  class

```
@Entity
//@Table(name = "demande")
public class ClientDao {


    @Column(name = "Id")

    private int  id ;

    @Column(name = "groupe")
    private String  groupe;

    @Column(name = "client")
    private String Client ;

    @Column(name = "quantite")
    private int  quantite ;


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getGroupe() {
        return groupe;
    }
    public void setGroupe(String groupe) {
        this.groupe = groupe;
    }
    public String getClient() {
        return Client;
    }
    public void setClient(String client) {
        Client = client;
    }
    public int getQuantite() {
        return quantite;
    }
    public void setQuantite(int quantite) {
        this.quantite = quantite;
    }




}
```

//Client Service

```
@Service
public interface ClientService {

    public  void saveUser(ClientDao clientdao);
}
```

// Client service Implementation

```
@Service
public class ClientServiceImpli implements ClientService{

    @Autowired
    private ClientReposito clientRepository;


    @Transactional
    public void saveUser(ClientDao clientdao) {
        clientRepository.saveAndFlush(clientdao);

   }

}
```

//Controller

```
@Controller
public class ClientController {

    private ClientService clientService;

    @Autowired
    public void setClientService(ClientService clientService){
        this.clientService=clientService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/index")  
    public String greeting(@RequestParam(name="name", required=false, defaultValue="World") String name, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("name", name);
        return "";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    public String welcome() {

         System.out.println("welcome page started");
         return "redirect:/index.html";

        }

    @GetMapping(path = "/thankyou")
    public String thankyou() {

         System.out.println("welcome page started");
         return "";

        }

}
```

//Full  exception

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
[2m2018-05-23 15:17:24.975[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m4052[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.s.boot.SpringApplication              [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'clientServiceImpli': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'clientRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'clientReposito': Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.PersistenceContext.synchronization()Ljavax/persistence/SynchronizationType;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:587) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:91) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:373) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1344) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:388) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1234) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at banque.Test.main(Test.java:11) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'clientReposito': Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.PersistenceContext.synchronization()Ljavax/persistence/SynchronizationType;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:560) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:584) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.PersistenceContext.synchronization()Ljavax/persistence/SynchronizationType;
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.<init>(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:653) ~[spring-orm-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.lambda$buildPersistenceMetadata$1(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:435) ~[spring-orm-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithLocalMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:522) ~[spring-core-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.buildPersistenceMetadata(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:420) ~[spring-orm-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findPersistenceMetadata(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:394) ~[spring-orm-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:332) ~[spring-orm-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1016) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    ... 33 common frames omitted
```

//POM.xml

```
  <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
  <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
  <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
  <version>6.0</version>
</dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.4.Final</version>
     </dependency>


     <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.3.Final</version>
</dependency>

    <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>

  </dependencies>
```

Comment: try changing `extends JpaRepository<ClientDao, Long>`  to `extends JpaRepository<ClientDao, Integer> ` or change your ClientDao id  from `int` to `Long`

Comment: besides, i believe the exception contains more usefull data

Comment: @MohamedELAYADI thanks  for your fast  respond  i did  it but  is still get the same error

Comment: Please post the full  exception. Your exception is telling us that it's unable to link the repository in service. what comes after this `Error creating bean with name 'clientReposito':

`

Comment: @MohamedELAYADI just added  it  thanks

Comment: now we need your pom.xml please :) (at least the dependencies)

Comment: @MohamedELAYADI just  added  it  lol :)

Comment: Please remove @Service annotation from Interface...\

Comment: @MohamedELAYADI did  but  nothing  changed :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two `hibernate-core` dependencies in your project. The one with `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` and the  other.

So you need to delete/exclude one  of them. I strongly suggest to remove the hibernate core dependency for compatiblity and to resume all the talks.

Comment: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: banque.ClientDao

Comment: that  is what  i get

Comment: corrected  that  it  works  .... thanks wish  i could upvote again ... thanks so  much